# Kafka Transaction in case multi Threading

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to create kafka producer in trasnsaction i.e. i want to write a group of msgs if anyone fails i want to rollback all the msg.

```
kafkaProducer.beginTransaction();
try
{
    // code to produce to kafka topic
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    kafkaProducer.abortTransaction();
}
kafkaProducer.commitTransaction();
```

The problem is for single thread above works just fine, but when multiple threads writes it throws exception

> Invalid transaction attempted from state IN_TRANSITION to IN_TRANSITION

while debugging I found that if the thread1 transaction is in progress and thread2 also says beingTransaction it throws this exception. What I dont find if how to solve this issue. One possible thing I could find is creating a pool of produce.

Is there any already available API for kafka producer pool or i will have to create my own.

Below is the improvement jira already reported for this.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6278

Any other suggestion will be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single transaction in progress at a time with a producer instance.

If you have multiple threads doing separate processing and they all need exactly once semantics, you should have a producer instance per thread.

Comment: Is there any api available in kafka for ProducerPool so that we do not create as many producer and then close them.

Comment: This is not part of the Apache Kafka API. Some frameworks like spring-kafka have provide this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was resolved.
you can use apache common pool2 to create a producer instance pool.
In the create() method of the factory implementation you can generate and assign a unique transactionalID to avoid a conflict (ProducerFencedException)